# Question about computing cohomology of trivial action on $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I'm currently considering the trivial action of the group $G = \mathbb{Z}_{2}$ on the group $A = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.

It is easy to show that $|C^{2}(G,A)|$ = $2^{8}$ and that $|B^{2}(G,A)| \leq 2^{4}$.

However, how would one show, using cocycle conditions that $|Z^{2}(G,A)| \leq 2^{4}$ and that $|H^{2}(G,A)| = 2$ by using showing inequivalent extensions of G by A and their cocycles?
I'm not sure how to proceed via using the cocycle condition to do this. By the way, this is problem 2 from D&F section 17.4.

Thanks!

Comment: I understand that $ Z $ refers to co-cycles, $ B $ to co-boundaries and $ H $ to the quotient of $ Z $ by $ B $, but what does $ C $ refer to?

Comment: It's the cochain complex

Comment: I see. Then it’d be better to write a co-chain complex as $ {C^{\bullet}}(G,A) $.

Comment: Oh alright. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Maybe looking at the long exact sequence corresponding to the (non-trivial) extension $0 \to \mathbb Z/2 \to \mathbb Z/4 \to \mathbb Z/2 \to 0$ with trivial $G$-actions helps?